# SQLAlchemy 2 Can't add additional column when specifying __table__

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am upgrading from SQLAlchemy 1.4 to SQLAlchemy 2 and I am running into an error: `Can't add additional column 'machine_id' when specifying __table__` when trying to create a versioned history table with inherited columns. Following the example [SQLAlchemy example](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/main/examples/versioned_history/history_meta.py):

```
    versioned_cls = type(
        "%sHistory" % cls.__name__,
        bases,
        {
            "_history_mapper_configured": True,
            "__table__": history_table,
            "__mapper_args__": dict(
                inherits=super_history_mapper,
                polymorphic_identity=local_mapper.polymorphic_identity,
                polymorphic_on=polymorphic_on,
                properties=properties,
            ),
        },
    )
```

```
class MachineIdMixin(object):
    @declared_attr.cascading
    def machine_id(self) -> Mapped[String]:
        return mapped_column(String, ForeignKey("machines.id"), nullable=False, index=True)
```

```
class MyTable(Base, MachineIdMixin, Versioned):
    __table__ = "mytable"
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

When attempting to run however I get the following error: `Can't add additional column 'machine_id' when specifying __table__`. When debugging on that line, the passed in column is `machine_id` whereas `mytable_history` as a column `mytable_history.machine_id`, and it incorrectly identifies as a column to be added. I've also checked: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_mixins.html#using-orm-declared-attr-to-generate-table-specific-inheriting-columns and it seems the mixin definition is correct. Is there something I am doing incorrectly?